# How to Change Default Baud rate of Thermal printer ? (CSN-A1)

Tags: arduino, thermal-printer

I have a (csn-A1) thermal printer with 19200 default baud rate. but this baud rate is too slow for print image.

my question is how can i change default baud rate from 19200 to 115200 by (Arduino or TTL usb serial ).

Notice: i found  an  unofficial software( Printer Setting Tool.exe ) that didn't work too.

Please Help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

The serial interface documentaiton does not specify any commands to change the baud rate.

From what I see the baud rate cannot be changed and due to the slow printing speed and the limited print buffer higher transmission rates would only cause overflows.

Comment: Yes there is no documentation but  My friend once did it with unofficial software.  But unfortunately he has forgotten the solution !.

Comment: http://www.dkia.at/downloads/csn-a2-t-tool.zip (software link) ,     https://www.dkia.at/en/node/129#comment-15503  (claim link) , 
this link claims to be done by a specific method and software!                                i did it over and over with TTL serial & Arduino  but i can't find solution.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily expect  a tool for csn-a2 to work for csn-a1

Comment: Yes sure, but my friend did that with same software for CSN-A1 and CSN-A2 .